# Find a constant (a class) scoped to a specific namespace (a module)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to programmatically fetch a constant (e.g. a class), but want to only look at the constants defined in a specific namespace. However, `const_get` will bubble up to higher namespaces while searching for the constant. For instance:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

class Quux
end
```

If you then ask `Foo` to return the constant `"Bar"`, it'll return the correct class.

```
Foo.const_get('Bar')
#=> Foo::Bar
```

However, if you ask it for `"Quux"`, it'll bubble up it's search path and find the top-level Quux:

```
Foo.const_get('Quux')
#=> Quux
```

Is there any way to make it **only** search in the module that `const_get` is called on?

Comment: *+1* for creating good and clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`Module#const_get`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get) says:

> Checks for a constant with the given name in mod If inherit is set, the lookup will also search the ancestors (and Object if mod is a Module.)
>
> The value of the constant is returned if a definition is found, otherwise a NameError is raised.

You can then do as below:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

class Quux
end

Foo.const_get('Quux',false) rescue NameError
# >> NameError
Foo.const_get('Bar',false) rescue NameError
# >> Foo::Bar
```